# Repeat column headers in print mode using Tabulator table

Tags: tabulator

Using chrome: 72.0.3626.96

What is the correct approach to configure the styles on a Tabulator table such that when printing, a table that spans multiple pages will have its header repeated on each page ?

(Suppose there are no other elements in the body of the html other than the Tabulator elements.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently available on Tabulator. it is on the roadmap to ad advanced print styling, but this wont be for a while yet

Comment: Hi @oli-folkerd, is this feature available yet?

Comment: Yes, http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/print

Comment: Awesome!. But the documentation still says `Print Header Placement
The print header will be inserted above the table on the printout, this will only occur on the first page of the print out, this should not be used as a page header.`

Comment: that refers to a title shown above the table not the table itself